# What is unchecked and unsafe operation here?

Tags: java, generics, collections, hashset

I have the following code:

```
private static final Set<String> allowedParameters;
static {
    Set<String> tmpSet = new HashSet();
    tmpSet.add("aaa");
    allowedParameters = Collections.unmodifiableSet(tmpSet);
}
```

And it cause:

```
Note: mygame/Game.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

And when I recompile with the suggested option I see a pointer (^) pointing at "new" in front of `HashSet();`.

Does anybody know what is going on here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you're creating a new HashSet without stating what class it should contain, and then asserting that it contains strings.  Change it to

```
 Set<String> tmpSet = new HashSet<String>();
```

Answer (score 2):

these messages occur when you are using classes that support the new J2SE 1.5 feature - generics. You get them when you do not explicitly specify the type of the collection's content.

For example:

```
List l = new ArrayList();
list.add("String");
list.add(55);
```

If you want to have a collection of a single data type you can get rid of the messages by:

```
List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("String");
```

If you need to put multiple data types into once collection, you do:

```
List<Object> l = new ArrayList<Object>();
list.add("String");
list.add(55);
```

If you add the -Xlint:unchecked parameter to the compiler, you get the specific details about the problem.

for more details refer here : http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=584311