# Arraylist - compiler is confusing me

Tags: java, generics, collections

For some reason, when I compile this simple code, an error pops up. (If I had 10 rep I would post it) It basically says (File Directory) uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Recompile with -Xlint: unchecked for details. I experimented a little and it seems if I take away the `Bin.add()` the error goes away. Can someone explain what I should do?

[image: ERROR!!!]

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Summoned_Bin
{

ArrayList Bin = new ArrayList();

Summoned_Bin()
{

}

void addToBin()
{
    Summon summoned = new Summon();
    int index = 0;
    while (Bin.get(index) != null)
    {
        index++;
    }
    Bin.add(index , summoned ); //Without this it runs fine
}

}
```

Comment: Why can't you post it?  (If you were going to post an image, please don't!  Post the error text instead.)

Comment: Why shouldn't I post the picture? And the thing about this error is that it poped out in a window (like a JFrame)

Comment: Because you should post the exact text of the error.  You should have probably started by googling the exact text of the error.  That's where I always start if I'm stuck.

Comment: Because text will appear in web search, etc.

Comment: calling list.get(x) for an index which doesnt exist will cause an Exception. just call bin.add(object) to add an object to the end of the list.

Comment: Both would be okay, I guess.  A little overkill.  Just be sure to type the text in.

Comment: You want to add something at the end of list, why not just use `list.add(object)` method?

Comment: The point of putting it in the next open spot is because I'm planning on deleting some summons later.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is unchecked and unsafe operation here?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419216/what-is-unchecked-and-unsafe-operation-here)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it wants you to type the list `List<Summon> Bin = new ArrayList<Summon>();`

Three things to note:

Declare the type as `List<Summon>` instead of `ArrayList<Summon>` its best practice to use the interface, which will allow you to change the type at a later date.

The `Summoned_Bin` class should follow Java naming standards, so `SummonedBin` should be the name.

Also the name of the `SummonedBin` object should follow Java naming standards, use `bin` instead of `Bin`.

**Revised Class**

```
public class SummonedBin {

    List<Summon> bin = new ArrayList<Summon>();

    SummonedBin() {

    }

    void addToBin() {
        Summon summoned = new Summon();
        int index = 0;
        while (bin.get(index) != null) {
            index++;
        }
        bin.add(index, summoned); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Noticed that when I set up an example in my IDE.

Comment: Sorry about the naming, didn't expect to share the code with anyone.

Comment: @Programmer-Lvl1 No problem just some recommendations.

Answer (score 2):

It's not error, it's only warning.

You want to do explicit type definition:

```
ArrayList<Summon> Bin = new ArrayList<Summon>();
```

Comment: Worked! But why? I thought that you could put multiple variable types and objects in the same ArrayList?

Comment: Never do that, you dont know what you got out if you have multiple object types in there

Comment: To supplement what blub said, that is the whole reason generics were introduced, well and to avoid casts.

Comment: So what does the <Summon> do? Reserves it for a object type?

Comment: It specifies the type of elements permissible to be inserted into the list and allows objects retreived from the list to be typed properly without a cast.  This checking is all performed at compile time.  Its called `generics`.

Comment: Elements being a class?