# Can't find .get() in Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

For some reason `.get()` isn't a valid method in my code. Can somebody point out the error? (Sorry for the improper object names (wasn't planning on sharing this code))

```
public class Summon_Tester
{
  public static void main (String [] Args)
  {
    Summoned_Bin Bin = new Summoned_Bin();
    Bin.addToBin();
    System.out.println(Bin.get(0));
  }
}
```

Summoned_Bin code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Summoned_Bin
{
  ArrayList<Summon> Bin = new ArrayList<Summon>();

  Summoned_Bin()
  {
  }

  void addToBin()
  {
    Summon summoned = new Summon();
    int index = 0;
    while (Bin.get(index) != null)
    {
      index++;
    }
    Bin.add(index , summoned );
  }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Arraylist - compiler is confusing me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20557723/arraylist-compiler-is-confusing-me)

Comment: How is this a duplicate?

Comment: Maybe you meant `Bin.Bin.get(0)`? Although the solution in the following answer is more suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Summoned_Bin isn't an ArrayList as it does not extend the ArrayList class. Rather, it  **contains** an ArrayList. Know that this is fine, it's quite OK to enhance a class through composition and not inheritance, but just don't try to use any ArrayList methods directly on it.

You have two common solutions:

1. You can make it extend ArrayList, but I'm not sure that this is the best thing to do, or
2. You **can** give it public methods that allow outside classes to extract information.

For example, give it a `get(...)` method:

```
public Summon get(int index) {
  return Bin.get(index);
}
```

---

**Edit**
As nachokk rightly suggests, you will want to learn and follow [Java code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html), as doing this will make it much easier for others to understand your code.

Comment: As a note (not to you hover) please follow [java code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)  and stick to them!

Comment: As I said "Sorry for the improper object names(wasn't planning on sharing the code)"

Comment: @Programmer-Lvl1 it hasn't proper indentation even for you is difficult to read

Comment: @Programmer-Lvl1: you will want all your code including your "private" code to adhere to convention. By following good coding habits, you enforce them, and they will then persist in your future code without even thinking about them.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your option 2? (Got your advice on the coding habits) Edit: thinking of something else... (Sorry)

Comment: @Programmer-Lvl1: um,... I thought that I did! Please see the method that I posted.